# how to use gson to convert json to string

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert from json to Java object. I am receiving a json string that includes a list of books:

```
[{"author":"Jonathan Khatz",
 "id":8,
 "name":"Criptography  6",
 "publisher":"Chapman",
 "year":2010},
 {"author":"Hausi Muller",
 "id":9,
 "name":"SelfAdaptiveSystem",
 "publisher":"UVic",
 "year":2010}]
```

And I have created an object called Books:

```
package RESTful.client.model;

public class Books {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private int year;
    private String publisher;

    public Books(){
    }

    public Books(int id, String name, String author, int year, String publisher){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.author=author;
        this.year=year;
        this.publisher=publisher;
    }

    // public Getter & Setter methods
}
```

Also I am using the doGet method to retrieve this data from a RESTful webservice in this way:

```
package RESTful.client.getBooks;
import RESTful.client.model.*;

// imports omitted

/**
 * Servlet implementation class GetBooksByYear
 */
@WebServlet("/GetBooksByYear")
public class GetBooksByYear extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetBooksByYear() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Client client= Client.create();
        //PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        String year= request.getParameter("year");
        System.out.println("Year to search: "+year);                 
        WebResource webResource= client.resource("http://localhost:8080/library/webapi/books/year/"+year);
        ClientResponse rs=webResource.accept(
                           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
                           MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).
                           get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println("Get operation response processing...\n");
        String jsonBooks=rs.getEntity(String.class);

        //kajacx solution:
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Books[] booksA = gson.fromJson(jsonBooks, Books[].class);
        List<Books> books = Arrays.asList(booksA);
        for(Books book : books) {
            System.out.println(book.getName()+", "+book.getAuthor()+", "+book.getAuthor()+", "+ book.getYear());
        }

    }
```

However, I am getting an error when executing:
List books = new Gson().fromJson(jsonBooks, new TypeToken>(){}.getType());

The exception is the next:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    RESTful.client.getBooks.GetBooksByYear.doGet(GetBooksByYear.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

[image]

[image]

The output with Java list:
Criptography 6, Jonathan Khatz, Jonathan Khatz, 2010
SelfAdaptiveSystem, Hausi Muller, Hausi Muller, 2010

The json book format is: [{"author":"Jonathan Khatz","id":8,"name":"Criptography 6","publisher":"Chapman","year":2010},{"author":"Hausi Muller","id":9,"name":"SelfAdaptiveSystem","publisher":"UVic","year":2010}]

Cheers

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson`. Looks like you forgot to add the Gson library.

Comment: Hi Boris, they are included in the import area: import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Comment: Yes, that we know - otherwise you would not have been able to compile. You also must have included the `.jar` in your compile time classpath. But you have not got the `.jar` on your run time classpath - i.e. in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the `.war`.

Comment: the libraries are included in EAR Libraries. I included as an external java file through java Built Path.

Comment: They exist in in the project but are not copied into the build. Find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, since this how I always use GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String data = "[{\"author\":\"Jonathan Khatz\", \"id\":8,"
    + "\"name\":\"Criptography  6\","
    + "\"publisher\":\"Chapman\", \"year\":2010},"
    + "{\"author\":\"Hausi Muller\", \"id\":9,"
    + "\"name\":\"SelfAdaptiveSystem\","
    + "\"publisher\":\"UVic\", \"year\":2010}]";

Book[] books = gson.fromJson(data, Book[].class);
Arrays.asList(books).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And it works fine. Also I renamed `Books` to `Book` since the class represents only one book.

Comment: Sorry, I got a mistake that I can not figure out what is happening in the next: 
Books[] booksA = gson.fromJson(jsonBooks, Books[].class);
Arrays.asList(booksA).forEach(System.out::println);
I am getting an error: The Method forEach (in the type iterable <Books>  is not applicable for the arguments (PrintStream)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question with the solution that you provided me. I change a little bit because I got some troubles.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is exactly what you need.. but I'm using gson like this.

`Gson gson = new Gson();`
`Object json = gson.fromJson(stringJson, Class);`

Comment: This is only tangentially related to the question. Certainly not an answer.